# Alfresco community version 5.2. Getting error message while trying to preview alfresco TIFF thumbnail image

Tags: alfresco

I have installed alfresco community version 5.2. Getting error message "This document can't be previewed" while trying to preview alfresco TIFF thumbnail image.

Comment: Can you share your alfresco logs ?

Comment: That should work. Can u check the mimeType of your image? http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/valid-transformations-preview.html

Answer (score 2):

TIFF images are previewable out-of-the-box. However, you must have ImageMagick installed on your Alfresco server. And Alfresco has to know where the ImageMagick binary is.

If you are on Linux, type "which convert" and make sure that something comes back. You can also type "convert -version" to verify that it is installed.

Also, check your alfresco-global.properties file for the ImageMagick related config entries. Out-of-the-box they probably look something like:

```
img.root=/opt/alfresco/common
img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
```

If all that is correct then you must have something mis-configured or maybe you've overridden the out-of-the-box transformers with your own and made some mistakes there.

Comment: ImageMagick is broken on a fresh install of 5.2 community on Windows. I can see this problem was fixed for Enterprise but there has been no patch for community.